# Profiling Microsoft Dynamics SL 7 (Solomon) performance issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are using Microsoft Dynamics SL 7 (Solomon) and are having performance issues when logging into the application and pulling up information associated with accounts.  Aside from a very generic approach to diagnosing the problem(s) such as running SQL Profiler, I was wondering if there was an SL specific approach to discovering performance bottlenecks and correcting them.  If there isn't a specific approach, I'd really appreciate a strategy that can be applied.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick one that should help.  Won't solve all of your issues.  In IE, Options, Advanced, scroll down to the Security section and disable checking certificates.